# How to find limit of this integral???

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I had this problem on my last exam,and I couldn't do it:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}}dt}{x^{5}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\frac{e^{t}}{t^{2}} dt}
\end{align}$$

Usually,we get only one integral along with some function(like $ x^5$ here),and with some substitution ,we convert it to fraction of integral and some function,then we must prove it is in form of $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so we can use L'Hopital's rule.However,i have no idea how to solve this kind of problems.Can someone help me on this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may be able to apply L'Hopital's rule here.

Comment: Note that the integral $\int_0^{x^2} \frac{e^t}{t^2}$ does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f'(x)=e^{x^2}, g'(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}$, by chain rule we get, $(g(x^2))'=\frac{2e^{x^2}}{x^3}$

Not hard to check it's $\inf/\inf$ form and those functions behave well so we can use L'Hôpital's rule.

$lim_{x->\inf} \frac{f(x)}{x^5g(x^2)}=lim_{x->\inf} \frac{e^{x^2}}{5x^4g(x^2)+2x^2e^{x^2}}$

In the last expression notice the first term of denominator is positive and if you omit that term the limit is clearly 0, by squeeze theorem the finial limit is 0 therefore the original limit is 0.

Comment: nice hint...thank you